# Laravel redirect away method redirects to own domain

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, laravel-8, urlbinding

I am coding a Laravel API hosted on **api.url.com** for an application hosted on **[www.myurl.com](http://www.myurl.com)** on a server different to the Lravel API using Laravel Fortify.

The problem comes when the user verifies their email on the generated link, they are redirected not to the external application but again back to the API, but on their browser.

THe docs state that this configuration in the Authenticate.pgp Middleware would work:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate as Middleware;

class Authenticate extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * Get the path the user should be redirected to when they are not authenticated.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return string|null
     */
    protected function redirectTo($request)
    {
        if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
            return url(env('SPA_URL') . '/dashboard');
        }
    }
}
```

Where SPA_URL is set in the .env to [www.myurl.com](http://www.myurl.com).

This redirects to **api.url.com/www.myurl.com/dashboard** Obviously causing a 404 response.

I then tried to call an action on a controller as such

```
public function redirectDashboard(Request $request){
        return redirect()->away('www.myurl.com/dashboard');
    }
```

This **again** redirects to **api.url.com/www.myurl.com/dashboard** Obviously causing a 404 response.

I have no clue why redirect()->away would still redirect to a url on the same API domain.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Add https:// and then try `return redirect()->away('https://www.myurl.com/dashboard');`

Answer (score 0):

The `RedirectTo` method will redirect to request.

Try to write new middleware

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    //check here if the user is authenticated
    if ( ! $this->auth->user() )
    {
        // here you should redirect to another site
        return redirect(env('SPA_URL') . '/dashboard');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: I found the solution and will post it shorlty but thank you for your time regardless.

Answer (score 0):

I finally realised what was happening with the redirect: I was using the `redirect()` helper function rather than the `Redirect::class`. The helper function appends the current domain to any `url` or `away` method call whereas the `Redirect::class` allows you to redirect to anywhere you need.